# Cloudera Administration - installation of CDH thru Cloudera Manager

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I've chosen to install CDH through Automated installer using Cloudera Manager, the download completes but unable to push through due this error:

```
Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.
Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager Server (check firewall rules).
Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are not in use on the host being added.
Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added. (Some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
If Use TLS Encryption for Agents is enabled in Cloudera Manager (Administration -> Settings -> Security), ensure that /etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini has use_tls=1 on the host being added. Restart the corresponding agent and click the Retry link here.
```

However upon checking the details, I saw **Failed to connect to previous supervisor** in this error details:

```
Installation script completed successfully.
all done
closing logging file descriptor
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:34:30 +0000] 4355 MainThread agent INFO Re-using pre-existing directory: /run/cloudera-scm-agent/supervisor
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:34:30 +0000] 4355 MainThread agent INFO Re-using pre-existing directory: /run/cloudera-scm-agent/flood
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:34:30 +0000] 4355 MainThread agent INFO Re-using pre-existing directory: /run/cloudera-scm-agent/supervisor/include
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:34:30 +0000] 4355 MainThread agent        ERROR    Failed to connect to previous supervisor.
>>Traceback (most recent call last):
>> File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf-5.12.0-py2.7.egg/cmf/agent.py", line 2109, in find_or_start_supervisor
>> self.configure_supervisor_clients()
>> File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf-5.12.0-py2.7.egg/cmf/agent.py", line 2290, in configure_supervisor_clients
>> supervisor_options.realize(args=["-c", os.path.join(self.supervisor_dir, "supervisord.conf")])
>> File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 1599, in realize
>> Options.realize(self, *arg, **kw)
>> File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 333, in realize
>> self.process_config()
>> File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 341, in process_config
>> self.process_config_file(do_usage)
>> File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 376, in process_config_file
>> self.usage(str(msg))
>> File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.7.egg/supervisor/options.py", line 164, in usage
>> self.exit(2)
>>SystemExit: 2
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:34:30 +0000] 4355 Dummy-1 daemonize WARNING Stopping daemon.
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:34:30 +0000] 4355 Dummy-1 agent INFO Stopping agent...
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:34:30 +0000] 4355 Dummy-1 agent INFO No extant cgroups; unmounting any cgroup roots
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO SCM Agent Version: 5.12.0
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Agent Protocol Version: 4
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Using Host ID: b9e306ab-b527-4667-9f3e-b6acad9f5224
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Using directory: /run/cloudera-scm-agent
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Using supervisor binary path: /usr/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/bin/supervisord
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Neither verify_cert_file nor verify_cert_dir are configured. Not performing validation of server certificates in HTTPS communication. These options can be configured in this agent's config.ini file to enable certificate validation.
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Agent Logging Level: INFO
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO No command line vars
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Missing database jar: /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar (normal, if you're not using this database type)
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Missing database jar: /usr/share/java/oracle-connector-java.jar (normal, if you're not using this database type)
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Found database jar: /usr/share/cmf/lib/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar
>>[18/Jul/2017 01:39:14 +0000] 5611 MainThread agent INFO Agent starting as pid 5611 user root(0) group root(0).
```

This is my current setup.

CentOS 7.2
Installing CDH 5.11.1 or 5.12 using Cloudera Manager.
4 nodes

/etc/hosts

```
192.168.0.101 node1.cirro.com node1
192.168.0.102 node2.cirro.com node2
192.168.0.103 node3.cirro.com node3
192.168.0.104 node4.cirro.com node4
```

/etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=myservers*.cirro.com
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

hostname has also been set per node to reflect /etc/sysconfig/network.

```
sestatus = disabled
firewalld = inactive
ntpd = active (running)
httpd = active (running)
vm.swappiness = 10
user = passwordless sudo
/etc/rc.local has been set
```

Can anyone help me on this? I've been stuck with this for 2 weeks now. I've run out of options and searching online. It would be really appreciated!

Comment: Did you check that port are avaiable ? try a telnet on each node the ports...

Comment: Thanks kulssaka, updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after updating to a higher version.